# Crontab doesn't work with wget

Tags: linux, cron

I set the following cron tab when I'm under root user.

```
* * * * * wget -q --spider http://mytargeturl.com/my/url/
```

The codes are under the same server but owned by another user (and I couldn't set a crontab with that user). I have to request the page with wget because of MVC link system complexity.

When I run:

```
crontab -l -u root
```

I can see this crontab setting.

Why would be the reason that crontab doesn't work?
Thanks.

Comment: If a crontab command gets an error you should get an email. Have you checked root's email?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks fine and this should work. Check /var/log/cron to make sure that it is indeed running, and if so, consider logging the command's output to a file and then inspect the file to pinpoint where the problem may be.